Can’t open .docx files with Files (Nautilus) into Wine MS Word
I have been using Ubuntu for a while, but still my knowledge is very limited.
Recently I got fed up with Windows 10, so I reinstalled Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS only.
I used to click on .docx files with Files, and I used to be able to open those with Microsoft Office 2007 (through Wine).
This time I run Office 2007 with Wine again, but when I double click on a .docx file, it runs MS Word but it doesn’t load the file I clicked.
Can anyone help me to solve this? Please explain for an Ubuntu beginner.
Thanks a lot.

Please edit and add when it did work. What version of Ubuntu.

if you right click with the mouse on the file in question and select Open with... you should be able to select the app required from the list presented. You should also be able to open the docx file successfully in LibreOffice Calc

after you have performed that task the first time, it should remember it for the future which is probably why it worked under your old version.
